# $\lim_{\hat{h} \to \hat{0}} \frac{\|L(\hat{h})\|}{\|\hat{h}\|} = 0 ~~~~ \Longrightarrow ~~~~ L \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear function. Proof that
$$\lim_{\hat{h} \to \hat{0}} \frac{\|L(\hat{h})\|}{\|\hat{h}\|} = 0 ~~~~ \Longrightarrow ~~~~ L \equiv 0$$

What I've done:

We define the function $f: A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows,
$$f(\hat{h}) = \frac{\|L(\hat{h})\|}{\|\hat{h}\|}$$ and we have that $\hat{0} \in A'$.

By hypothesis, as the limit is zero, for $\epsilon = 1$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$0 < \|\hat{h}\| < \delta ~~~~ \Longrightarrow ~~~~ \frac{\|L(\hat{h})\|}{\|\hat{h}\|} < 1$$

Since $\hat{h} \to \hat{0}$, we can consider those vectors that satisfies that $\|\hat{h}\| < \delta$ thus,
$$\frac{\|L(\hat{h})\|}{\|\hat{h}\|} < 1 ~~~~ \Longrightarrow ~~~~ 0 \leqslant \|L(\hat{h})\| < \|\hat{h}\| ~~~~ \Longrightarrow ~~~~ \|L(\hat{h})\| = 0 ~~~~ \Longrightarrow ~~~~ L \equiv 0$$

I'm not entirely sure of the validity of the proof...

Comment: Why $\|L(h)\|<\|h\|\implies \|L(h)\|=0$ ?

Comment: @Surb because $\hat{h} \to \hat{0}$ and muss happen that $\|\hat{h}\| = 0$..

Comment: It just prove that $L(0)=0$...

Comment: You *must* use linearity of $L$ at some point…

Comment: Instead you can try and prove that the derivative(matrix) of a linear map is itself. Hence conlcude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|L(h)\|}{\|h\|}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|L(x+h)-L(x)\|}{\|h\|}$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Therefore, you get that $L$ is a constant function. Since $L(0)=0$, $L=0$.

Comment: It was too simple to think about it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**An other proof**

We wish proving that $$\|L\|:=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|L(x)\|=0.$$

Let $(x_n)$ s.t. $\|x_n\|\leq 1$ and $$\|L\|-\frac{1}{n}\leq \|L(x_n)\|.$$

In particular, $$\|L\|-\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{\|L(x_n/n)\|}{\|x_n/n\|}\|x_n\|\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$
Therefore $\|L\|=0$, and thus $L\equiv 0$ as wished.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof: Fix $h$ with $\| h\|=1$ and for $\lambda>0$ let $v_{\lambda}=\lambda h$. Then
$$
\| Lh\|= \dfrac{\| L h\|}{\| h\|}= \dfrac{\| Lv_{\lambda}\|}{\| v_\lambda\|} \overset{\lambda\to 0}{\to} 0.
$$
Since $h$ was any unit vector, it follows $L\equiv 0$.